# Sublime Text and Multiple Selection with CMD + D

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

OS X, Sublime Text 3

I can double click a word and use `CMD + D` to select the next instance of the word.

However if I want to replace this 30 times I need to `CMD + D` 30 times.

Is there a way to have it select all that it finds?

```
OpeningScene* OpeningScene::pinstance = 0;

OpeningScene* OpeningScene::Instance()
{
    if (pinstance == 0)
    {
        pinstance = new OpeningScene;
        pinstance->initInstance();
    }

    return pinstance;
}

OpeningScene::OpeningScene() { }
```

In the above, replacing `OpeningScene` I'd need to `CMD + D` 6 times after double clicking the first instance.

I guess I could do a Find/Replace using the dialog but is there a keyboard way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Put your cursor over the word and type:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

This should do a quick find all on your current word.

Comment: Ah, they call it Quick Find. Now I see works perfect. Thank you very much